# What to do if I can't find the book of this chapter I found so I can cite it?

Tags: online-resource

So I've found a .pdf file that is apparently a chapter of a book and I can't see any information about the book whatsoever aside from its title and the number of the chapter. I've tried entering a sentence from the chapter on google books and found 0 resemblance from the results that came up. Here's is the file :

https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/864/10/10_chapter%203.pdf

One thing is that I've found out that the file came from an Indian research database website but I've also tried searching for keywords from the file on the site and found nothing either. Considering the citation from the chapter, it's made around early 2000's. Are there any other ways to find the source of this chapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is chapter 3 of the following thesis:
https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/864

Title: Economics of solid waste management in Calicut corporation

Comment: This has provided the OP with the source, but is unlikely to be helpful to other readers when faced with a similar problem or to the OP should the problem arise again. Could you perhaps revise your answer to make if more broadly useful/applicable?